# PHP Break up a string into blocks of 5

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a long string of comma separated values that I feed into $users. I want to break up $users into blocks of 3 users each, and for each block, loop these actions:

```
$url = "http://myapi.com/info.json?key=$key&users=$users";
$response = wp_remote_get($url);

if (is_wp_error($result)) {
  echo "No Results from Provider. Sorry.";
  exit;
} else {
    if (wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response) == 200) {
    $json = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response),true);
  }
}
```

(References for [wp_remote_get](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_get) & [wp_remote_retrieve_body](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_API/wp_remote_retrieve_body))

Obviously, for each iteration of the loop, $json will have to be appended to the previous result. $json prints out as:

```
Array ( [status] => 200 [users] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [username] => user1 [total] => 4 ) [1] => Array ( [username] => user2 [total] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [username] => user3 [total] => 8 ) ) )
```

Ideally, at the end I would have one long merged array (no need for multiple [status]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use [explode](http://fi.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to separate the usernames into an array, then use [array_chunk](http://fi.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to get groups of three, do your calls, and finally use [array_splice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) to merge the results into one big array.